# Add parameters to dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

I would like to set some parameters to my `dag` file. I would like to add two parameters named:  `is_debug` and `seti`. I would also like to set `default values` to them so if i do not specify them when running manually a `dag` them to be `is_debug=False and seti='FG'`. How can i achieve that? Please also instruct me how should i insert the values when triggering manually the `dag` from `GUI` in `Configuration JSON (Optional): {}`

This is my dag:

```
import lib.log as log
import traceback
import datetime
import json

def my_main(**kwargs):
    try:
        #if is_debug == True:
        #   log.log_it('U in debug mode')
        #else:
            log.log_it('U in normal mode')
        
        #if seti == 'FG':
        #   log.log_it('FG')
        #else:
        #   log.log_it('RX')


from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


dag = DAG(
    'my_main', 
    description='my_main', 
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023,6,8,1,0), 
    schedule_interval="0 1 * * *",
    catchup=False
)
task_my_main = PythonOperator(task_id='task_my_main_main', provide_context=True, python_callable=my_main, dag=dag)
```

Comment: use environment variable?

Comment: @PankajSinghand how to modify dag file to take those variables?

Comment: @Arie, do you want to set those values per dag_run (via config for example manually), or define it from outside for all the system (airflow variables/ system environment) ?

Comment: @ozs per dag_run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add params to the Dag and when you run it manually you can change it accordingly.

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Param
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

is_debug_param = "{{ params.is_debug }}"
seti_param = "{{ params.seti }}"


def my_main(is_debug: bool, seti: str):
    print(is_debug)
    print(seti)


with DAG(
        dag_id="my_main",
        description='my_main',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        params={
            "is_debug": Param(default=False, type="boolean", ),
            "seti": Param(default="FG", type="string", enum=["FG", "RX"]),
        },
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:
    task_my_main = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_my_main_main',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=my_main,
        op_kwargs={
            "is_debug": is_debug_param,
            "seti": seti_param,
        },
    )

    (
        task_my_main
    )
```

if you run it manually, you can trigger it with or without config

[image]

if you trigger it with config, you can fill the values you want otherwise it would be the defaults you set in the code.

[image]

Comment: can i alos leave kwargs in my_main means as follows: def my_main(**kwargs, is_debug: bool, seti: str):

Comment: @Arie, yes but after the parameters : def my_main(is_debug: bool, seti: str, **kwargs)

Comment: by the way i am getting error: `NameError: name 'Param' is not defined`

Comment: did you "from airflow.models import Param" ? you can just put default value if you are running on old airflow version

Comment: from after ading i got:  airflow.models import Param ImportError: cannot import name 'Param'

Comment: it might be an airflow version. you can set the params with default value only, for example: {"is_debug": False, "seti": "FG"}